# Несколько условия if в цикле for

Tags: javascript, if

Всем привет, есть задача: "Дан массив с элементами 2, 5, 9, 15, 0, 4. С помощью цикла for и оператора if выведите на экран столбец тех элементов массива, которые больше 3-х, но меньше 10."

1е решение:

```
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (s[i] > 3 && s[i] < 10) {
    console.log(s[i]);
  }
};
```

Помогите со вторым решением:

```
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (s[i] > 3) {
    console.log(s[i]);
  } else if (s[i] < 10) {
    console.log(s[i]);
  }
};
```

Почему выводит:
2
5
9
15
0
4
и как сделать, через несколько if стейтментов тоже самое, как в 1м примере?

Comment: Потому что правильным является только первый вариант. Сами подумайте как работает код во втором: сначала проверяется условие s[i] > 3, если оно истинно тогда выводит в консоль значение элемента массива s[i], если оно ложно тогда проверяется второе условие s[i] < 10, и если оно истинно тогда так же выводится значение элемента массива s[i]. Фактически условие во втором варианте s[i] > 3 или s[i] < 10.

Comment: Почему тогда не выводи сначала элементы > 3 (включая элементы больше 10), а после < 10 ( включая элементы меньше 3)?

Comment: так цикл то один. с чего ему вдруг сначала одни выводить потом другие? каждое число на каждой итерации попадает либо в одну либо в другую ветку, массив в таком случае будет выведен в исходном порядке.

Comment: @teran почему тогда соблюдается исходный порядок при выводе массива?

Comment: потому что ваш цикл последовательно перебирает элементы. И каждый элемент попадает либо в одну либо в другую ветку цикла, где и выводится сразу же в этой же итерации

Answer (score 2):

В вашем втором решении звучит как если число больше трех или меньше 10

```
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (s[i] > 3) {
    if (s[i] < 10) {
      console.log(s[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: То есть по факту, мы вкладываем второй стейтмент if в первыый? спасибо! А какие еще варианты решения есть?

Comment: Да еще десятком способов можно записать и проход по массиву и проверку условия, вопрос зачем? самым нормальным способом в данном случае является ваш первый вариант :) можно извратится и использовать сравнение с диапазоном :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let s = [2, 5, 9, 15, 0, 4];

for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  if (s[i] <= 3)
    continue;
  if (s[i] >= 10)
    continue;

  console.log(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: Неплохой вариант записи :)